# Why does "SyntaxError: (unicode error)" occur when raw string is in triple quotes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, unicode-escapes

Whenever I put triple quotes around a raw string, the following error occurs:

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 28-29: malformed \N character escape

I was wondering why this is the case and if there is any way to avoid it.

I have tried moving the triple quotes to align with various parts of the code but nothing has worked so far.

This runs without error:

```
final_dir = (r'C:\Documents\Newsletters')

'''
path_list = []
for file in os.listdir(final_dir):
    path = os.path.join(final_dir, file)
    path_list.append(path)
'''
```

But then this creates an error:

```
'''
final_dir = (r'C:\Documents\Newsletters')
path_list = []
for file in os.listdir(final_dir):
    path = os.path.join(final_dir, file)
    path_list.append(path)
'''
```

Comment: This literal in itself isn't an error. Do you mean when you `eval` this string it raises the error? That would be because you need to double escape the backslashes. They're within a string within a string, so you need to double them twice.

Comment: I'd be more worried why you're producing such source code literals though…

Comment: Sorry had the wrong piece of code in there. I need to extract the files in all the subfolders

Comment: Same thing still. With the updated code your `''''''` string literal now encounters the error, because `\N` is an invalid escape sequence.

Comment: Do you know why the error doen't occur for \D? And does that mean that the only solution is to put \\ instead?

Comment: Because `\N` has a meaning; `\D` doesn't: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals And the solution is the same as for the string within the string: escape the backslash, or prepend an `r` to the literal to make it a raw string.

Comment: But there is already an r before the string, shouldn't that then not produce an error @deceze?

Comment: This is the issue: `'''\N'''`. It doesn't matter that there's another quote inside that string.

Comment: There are no raw string literals in your second snippet.

Answer (score 2):

In a string literal like `'\N'`, `\N` has a special meaning:

> `\N{name}` Character named *name* in the Unicode database

<sup>*from [String and Bytes literals - Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)*</sup>

For example, `'\N{tilde}'` becomes `'~'`.

Since you're quoting code, you probably want to use a raw string literal:

```
r'\N'
```

For example:

```
>>> r"""r'C:\Documents\Newsletters'"""
"r'C:\\Documents\\Newsletters'"
```

Or you could escape the backslash:

```
'\\N'
```

The error doesn't occur for `\D` because it doesn't have a special meaning.

<sup>*Thanks to [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) for practically writing this answer in the comments*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for writing this up, I’d have thunk a small nudge in the comments would have sufficed… :)